# No blinking lights on PS3 controller

Tags: ps3

I have two joystick for PS3 one is the original from Sony but the other on isn't and uses a usb Bluetooth what happens is that I can't work whit both at the same time, when the Sony runs of battery the other one starts working and when this non original runs out of battery the Sony starts working, what do I do?

Comment: What is this "other one"?

Comment: Have you tried plugging in the Sony controller while using it?